# Proof with congruence of angles

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I came across a proof exercise from my proof work-book that I am stuck on.

The questions says:

Suppose we have angle *PQR* with *P, Q, and R* non-collinear, and ray *QS* distinct from ray *QR* such that angle *PQS* is congruent to angle *PQR*.  Prove that if angle *PQT* is congruent to angle *PQR*, then either ray *QT* = ray *QR* or ray *QT* = ray *QS.*

From the question I was able to get that angle PQS is congruent to angle PQS is congruent to angle PQR.  I am not sure where to go from here or what theorems to use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Michael

Comment: Angle ABC makes one appearance in this question, and then is never heard from again. Was it supposed to be something else?

Comment: @GerryMyerson  I've edited the question, could you give a hint?

Comment: No, but I'm sure someone will.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I hope so :)

Comment: I did. Any comments?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks a lot, I understand the proof you have given :).  I'd give it an up-vote, but I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll assume given a line segment PQ, and three distinct rays QR, QS, and QT, each making the same angle $x$ with PQ; we'll show this leads to a contradiction.

We'll assume $x$ is not a right angle; we'll come back to deal with that case later.

There's a line L through P, parallel to QR. This line meets the ray QS at U, and it meets the ray QT at V (this is where we need the assumption that $x$ is not a right angle). $\angle QPU=\angle PQU=x$, and $\angle QPV=\angle PQV=x$, so $\angle PUQ=\angle PVQ$. So line segments QU and QV make the same angle with line L, so these line segments are parallel. But that's impossible, since they meet at Q.

Now if $x$ is a right angle, then the line L through P parallel to QR can't meet either of the rays QS and QT --- if it did, you'd get a triangle with two right angles. So QR, QS, and QT are all rays through Q parallel to L. But that says there are (at least) two lines through Q parallel to L, which contradicts the parallel postulate, and we're done.